# Services with azure kubernetes not reachable

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to configure azure kubernetes cluster and created one on the portal.dockerized .net core webapi project and also published the image to azure container register. After applying manifest file , i get the message of service created and also the external IP. however when I do get pods I get status "Pending" all the time

```
  NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  kubdemo1api-6c67bf759f-6slh2   0/1       Pending   0          6h
```

here is my yaml manifest file, can someone suggest what is wrong here?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kubdemo1api
labels:
  name: kubdemo1api
spec:
  replicas: 1
strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
  maxSurge: 1
  maxUnavailable: 1
type: RollingUpdate
 minReadySeconds: 30
selector:
matchLabels:
  app: kubdemo1api
template:
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kubdemo1api
    version: "1.0"
    tier: backend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kubdemo1api
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 10
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 10
    image: my container registry image address
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 100Mi
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 10
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 10
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: azkubdemoapi1
spec: 
  ports: 
- 
  port: 80
selector: 
  app: kubdemo1api
  type: LoadBalancer
```

EDIT:
Output kubectl describe pods is this

here is it

```
Normal   Scheduled  2m                default-scheduler                  Successfully assigned default/kubdemo1api-697d5655c-64fnj to aks-agentpool-87689508-0
  Normal   Pulling    37s (x4 over 2m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-87689508-0  pulling image "myacrurl/azkubdemo:v2"
  Warning  Failed     37s (x4 over 2m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-87689508-0  Failed to pull image "my acr url": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://myacrurl/v2/azkubdemo/manifests/v2: unauthorized: authentication required, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://myacrurl/v2/azkubdemo/manifests/v2: unauthorized: authentication required]
  Warning  Failed     37s (x4 over 2m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-87689508-0  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    23s (x6 over 2m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-87689508-0  Back-off pulling image "myacrlurl/azkubdemo:v2"
  Warning  Failed     11s (x7 over 2m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-87689508-0  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: can you share output of `kubectl describe pod kubdemo1api-6c67bf759f-6slh2`

Comment: added in the question

Comment: The error shows you need to authenticate to your registry to pull the image. You can use the `imagePullSecrets` to authenticate to your registry. See the [example of ACR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Any more questions? Or if the advice works for you, I would add an answer to others who meet the same issue. Please let me know the result.

Comment: authenticating using imagePullSecrets did the job for me. before that however, i had to create secret in the cluster that is available to nodes to consume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the error that you provide, it shows you have to authenticate to pull the image from the Azure Container Registry.

Actually, you just need permission to pull the image and the `acrpull` role is totally enough. There are two ways to achieve it.

One is that just grant the AKS access to the Azure Container Registry. It's simplest on my side. Just need to create the role assignment for the service principal which the AKS used. See [Grant AKS access to ACR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#grant-aks-access-to-acr) for the whole steps.

The other one is that use the Kubernetes secret. It's a little more complex than the first one. You need to create a new service principal differ from the one AKS used and grant access to it, then create the kubernetes secret with the service principal. See [Access with Kubernetes secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#access-with-kubernetes-secret) for the whole steps.

Answer (score 0):

This Yaml is Wrong Can you provide the correct yaml, the intending are wrong. Try Below YAML

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kubdemo1api
  labels:
    name: kubdemo1api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  minReadySeconds: 30
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubdemo1api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubdemo1api
        version: "1.0"
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubdemo1api
        image: nginx
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 10
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: azkubdemoapi1
spec: 
  ports: 
  - port: 80
  selector: 
    app: kubdemo1api
  type: LoadBalancer
```